# Getting error on creating a package in SSIS VS2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

I am using VS2017 and SSMS 2017 and imported a `CSV` file in `FLAT FILE option` in **Data Flow tab** in `SSIS` and also created an**ADO NET SOURCE** database connection through my local server that stores the data in my database. But when am trying to create a connection between `FLAT FILE` and `ADO NET SOURCE`, by dragging the blue arrow from file option to `ADO NET option`, am getting this error. Can anybody provide some input on how to get rid of this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzwq9.png)

Comment: um.....What error?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of the error.

Comment: 1. Don't use screenshots, actually post the error. 2. Reread the answer below. If you read it and understand it you'll solve your problem.

Comment: Error is **ADO NET has no inputs or all of its inputs are already connected to other outputs. You may be able to edit the components to add new inputs to it**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to route the flat file source into another source component, which cannot be done. Did you mean to route the data into a destination?

Comment: Yes routing it to an ADO Net source which is a SQL server database.

Comment: @sparshbijawat What are you doing? Are you trying to send it to a SQL database or join it with records from a SQL database before sending it to a destination?

Comment: Am trying to send it to SQL database

Comment: @sparshbijawat Then you need to use a data `destination`, not a data `source`. You are attempting to route you flat file data `source` into a database data 'source', which will not work. You must route the flat file data`source` into a database data `destination`

Answer (score 0):

Error is that you have connected Source to Source.
Fix it by connecting Source to Destination, so that the package can build successfully.

Replace your ADO.NET SOURCE with ADO.NET DESTINATION and this error will be corrected.